# PowerShell Replace Pattern with Wildcard

Tags: regex, powershell, regexp-replace

I have a text file for subtitles, and i need to edit the format of time from (00:00:31:14) to (00:00:31,14).

The files looks like the below example, where the time pattern is variable.

```
2
00:00:31:14 --> 00:00:34:20
Before 9\11 I used to offer various organizations
```

I'm trying to do something as below, but with replace, can't skip the digits

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\EngOm\.vscode\File1.txt)-replace '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', '\\:\\:\\,\\' | Set-Content C:\Users\EngOm\.vscode\File1.txt
```

Comment: if the timecode doesn't appear in the text, you can search for `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(\d{2})` and replace it with `$1,$2`.

Comment: The time code appears in the file. The file looks like below pattern but repeated at various time stamps:

2
00:00:31:14 --> 00:00:34:20
Before 9\11 I used to offer various organizations


The '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' catches the time stamp properly, but the replacement, just need to skip all and edit the last : with ,